# Rename a variable in a for loop

Tags: linux, bash, nested-loops

Lets say i have a nested for loop:

```
for i in $test
do
    name=something

    for j in $test2
    do
        name2=something
        jj=$j | sed s/'tRap\/tRapTrain'/'BEEML\/BEEMLTrain'/g
        if [ name == name2 ]
        then
        qsub scrip.sh $i $j $jj
        fi
    done
done
```

Now the problem occurs when i try to rename the variable $j into variable $jj. I only get empty values back for submitting the script within the `if` statement. Is there another way to rename variables so that i can pass them through to the `if` part of the code?
PS. i tried 3 for loops but this makes the script awfully slow.

Comment: Just indented first `done` to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is piping the assignment into sed. Try something like

```
jj=$(echo $j | sed s/'tRap\/tRapTrain'/'BEEML\/BEEMLTrain'/g)
```

This uses command substitution to assign `jj`.

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot in 6 minutes i will accept youre answer ;)
I was already trying to fix this for a few hours did not realize this could also be done like your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct:

```
jj=$j | sed s/'tRap\/tRapTrain'/'BEEML\/BEEMLTrain'/g
```

In order to assign the output of a command to a variable you need to use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) like this:

```
jj=$(sed s/'tRap\/tRapTrain'/'BEEML\/BEEMLTrain'/g <<< "$j")
```

You may not even have to use `sed` because bash has in-built string replacement. For example, the following will replace `foo` with `bar` in the `j` variable and assign it to `jj`:

```
jj=${j//foo/bar}
```

There is also a problem with your if-statement. It should be:

```
if [ "$name" == "$name2" ]
```

Comment: thanks for the good explanation ;) +1 for you! I changed my if statement as well.

Comment: forgot to ask can you explain why "" are needed within the if statement

Comment: If one of the variables is empty, it will try to evaluate `[ == $name2]` for instance, which won't work. With the quotes, it will compare against an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

A tiny little thing:
Sed treats the first character after the action selector as the field separator.
Knowing this you can translate your expresion:

```
sed s/'tRap\/tRapTrain'/'BEEML\/BEEMLTrain'/g
```

into:

```
sed s%'tRap/tRapTrain'%'BEEML/BEEMLTrain'%g
```

So you don't have to worry about scaping your slashes when substituting paths. I normally use '%', but feel free to use any other character. I think the optimal approach would be using a non printable character:

```
SEP=$'\001' ; sed s${SEP}'tRap/tRapTrain'${SEP}'BEEML/BEEMLTrain'${SEP}g
```